# Are "USSD" engineering codes should work on ANY smartphone?

Tags: ussd

I personaly have Xiaomi Mi 9 SE. My family members have different smartphones but htey are all manufactured by Xiaomi: Mi Note 9 and Mi A3.

I'm trying to execute engineering code to display Bluetooth MAC-address. `*#*#232337#*#*` code should be able to do so. But all 3 smartphones fails: after I touch the last '*' button - the code dissapeares and nothing happens.

However some codes are working: `*#06#` and `*#*#4636#*#*`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: All codes do not run on all devices. It also depends on the network operator since they are used to communicate with them. They are also *not* standardized. [See USSD Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data)

Comment: @beeshyams I think that this wiki page is related to GSM codes only. The codes I'm talking are more likely to be `engineering` codes.

Comment: OK, I saw USSD in title and pointed that.  They also are USSD because you dial them //Even engineering codes are **not** standardized. All codes do not run on all devices even from the same OEM. It's upto them to enable or disable//They are also dependent on chipset

Comment: This [SO question addresses your concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2781374)

Comment: So what you refer to is not especially USSD, but belongs to the "parent" family of [MMI codes](https://berlin.ccc.de/~tobias/mmi-ussd-ss-codes-explained.html) – more specifically, "Manufacturer defined MMI codes". As the term suggests, while many of them are common to a broad range of devices/manufacturers, it's up to the manufacturer which ones are implemented. For example, `*#06#` (show IMEI) has very broad support (never heard of a device not supporting that). Codes for specific "factory menus" are usually not that broadly supported.

Comment: PS: there are also those defined by the "Android core system", like `*#*#4636#*#*`. Further, even apps can establish such "short codes"…